# WP Job Manager - Additional signup fields on the job submission form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a site with WP Job Manager. A user can currently sign up at the point of posting a new job by entering their email address and a username. Once the job has been submitted, the account is created and the user is taken to the preview page before publishing their job.

I would like to add two additional fields to this signup form: First Name and Last Name. When submitted, these fields should populate the user's meta `first_name` and `last_name`.

I have this function that will add the fields:

add_filter( 'wpjm_get_registration_fields', 'add_first_last_name_fields', 999999 );

```
function add_first_last_name_fields( $reg_fields ){
    if( empty( $reg_fields ) ){
        return [];
    }

    $generate_username_from_email      = job_manager_generate_username_from_email();
    $use_standard_password_setup_email = wpjm_use_standard_password_setup_email();
    $account_required                  = job_manager_user_requires_account();

    $registration_fields = [];
    if ( job_manager_enable_registration() ) {
        $registration_fields['create_account_email'] = [
            'type'        => 'text',
            'label'       => esc_html__( 'Your email', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'placeholder' => __( 'you@yourdomain.com', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'required'    => $account_required,
            // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Missing -- Just used to populate value when validation failed.
            'value'       => isset( $_POST['create_account_email'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['create_account_email'] ) ) : '',
        ];
        
        if ( ! $generate_username_from_email ) {
            $registration_fields['create_account_username'] = [
                'type'     => 'text',
                'label'    => esc_html__( 'Username', 'wp-job-manager' ),
                'required' => $account_required,
                // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Missing -- Just used to populate value when validation failed.
                'value'    => isset( $_POST['create_account_username'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['create_account_username'] ) ) : '',
            ];
        }

    $registration_fields['first_name'] = [
            'type'        => 'text',
            'label'       => esc_html__( 'First Name / Organisation', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'placeholder' => __( 'First Name', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'required'    => $account_required,
            // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Missing -- Just used to populate value when validation failed.
            'value'       => isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) : '',
        ];

    $registration_fields['last_name'] = [
            'type'        => 'text',
            'label'       => esc_html__( 'Last Name', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'placeholder' => __( 'Last Name', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'required'    => $account_required,
            // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Missing -- Just used to populate value when validation failed.
            'value'       => isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) : '',
        ];


        if ( ! $use_standard_password_setup_email ) {
            $registration_fields['create_account_password'] = [
                'type'         => 'password',
                'label'        => esc_html__( 'Password', 'wp-job-manager' ),
                'autocomplete' => false,
                'required'     => $account_required,
            ];
            $password_hint                                  = wpjm_get_password_rules_hint();
            if ( $password_hint ) {
                $registration_fields['create_account_password']['description'] = $password_hint;
            }
        }
    }

    return $registration_fields;
}
```

Then as far as I understand, I need to get the value of the inputted fields, and assign them to the user meta.

So far I have tried:

```
add_filter ('job_manager_create_account_data', 'create_additional_registration_fields');
function create_additional_registration_fields($new_user) {
  $new_user = [
    'user_login' => $registration_fields['create_account_username'],
    'user_email' => $registration_fields['create_account_email'],
    'first_name' => $registration_fields['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $registration_fields['last_name'],
  ];

  return $new_user;

}
```

But this throws me an error: `Cannot create a user with an empty login name.`

I'm relatively new to understanding Wordpress functions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is by creating a function that adds the custom fields:

```
add_filter( 'wpjm_get_registration_fields', 'job_manager_add_extra_fields', 10, 1 );

function job_manager_add_extra_fields( $registration_fields ){

    if ( job_manager_enable_registration() ) {

    $registration_fields['first_name'] = [
            'type'        => 'text',
            'label'       => esc_html__( 'First Name', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'required'    => 1,
            'value'       => isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) : '',
        ];

    $registration_fields['last_name'] = [
            'type'        => 'text',
            'label'       => esc_html__( 'Last name', 'wp-job-manager' ),
            'required'    => 1,
            'value'       => isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) : '',
        ];
        
    }

    return $registration_fields;
}
```

Next you need to save them upon job submission:

```
add_filter( 'job_manager_create_account_data', 'job_manager_save_extra_fields', 10, 1 );

function job_manager_save_extra_fields( $new_user ){
  
    $new_user['first_name'] = isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) : '';
    $new_user['last_name'] = isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) : '';

    return $new_user;
}
```